# Where is PowerPoint's equivalent of Word's normal.dotm?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Where PowerPoint stores default presentation file, opened each time program is started, a Word's `normal.dotm` equivalent (if it exists)?

Or how can I change some elements of file, that is always created, when opening PowerPoint?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Templates\

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm pretty sure, that this folder holds only standard templates, which you can access by hiting `File > New` in each Office program. I'm asking for a default template, which 99.99% is stored in `%APPDATA%` I have default Word's `normal.dot` template in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Templates`. I don't know, where PowerPoint stores its own default template and that's the reason, why I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerPoint 2016:

1. Set up a blank ppt to your desired specifications (slide size, font, color, theme, etc).
2. Save the ppt as "Blank.potx" in folder "C:\Users\insert-username-here\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates".

Note: Powerpoint will want to save this in a default template folder once you change the file type to .potx so make sure you set the file type first then change the folder location.

The next time you open Powerpoint the very first template will be "Default Theme" (your personalized default). Next to that will be the original "Blank Presentation" and all the other standard themes.

Answer (score 1):

#### Where does PowerPoint store default presentation files?

The exact locations and names are different for each version of PowerPoint.

See the link below for more information about each version..

> Normally when you start PowerPoint you can create a new blank
>   presentation or start a presentation based on one of the included
>   templates. But what if you want PowerPoint to base all new
>   presentations on your own template?
>
> You can, and it's easy. You just need to open your template or a
>   presentation based on it, save it in the correct location and give it
>   the right name. The exact locations and names are a different for each
>   version of PowerPoint.

Source [Create your own default presentation](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01010_Create_your_own_default_presentation.htm)

Comment: This is not quite the same thing, and should be explained in your answer.  Wor'd Normal.dot / Normal.dotm is the default formatting for every new file, and this answer, and all the rest on The Internet like it, simple give you a way to have a new template ***IFF*** you select the new template.  I think this is a shortcoming of Microsoft, but no one makes it clear anywhere.